# Let $A = ]0,1]$ Find and open cover with no finite sub-cover

Tags: compactness

Let $A = ]0,1]$ Find and open cover with no finite sub-cover.

I had constructed open cover such as $\{]1/n, 2[ :n = 1,2,3,...\}$ but can't be sure of whether this cover actually contain all of $A$. How could I prove that A actually contain all of $A$?

Comment: what is $]0,1]$?

Comment: Use the Archimedean property of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I think $]0,1]$ is French (or something) for $(0,1].$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown how?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo it means (0,1]. European notation

Comment: @Daschin it helps in proving that if $x>0$ then there is an integer $n>0$ with $1/n>x$.

Comment: @bof wow, this is the most horrible thing I have seen today.

Comment: You need to find $n$ such that $\frac1n\lt\varepsilon,$ right? $\frac1n\lt\varepsilon$ is the same as $n\gt\frac1\varepsilon.$ Use Archimedes.

Comment: what stereotipes?

Comment: Actually, ]0,1[ vs.  (0,1) has an advantage that it can not be confused for an ordered pair.  I've seen it a lot on this sight.  It looks odd to me but it's a bit much to call it "horrible".

Answer (score 1):

Consider the cover $A=]\frac{1}{n},1]$.

Suppose $B$ is a finite subset of $A$. Let $N$ be the largest value such that $]\frac{1}{N},1]$ is in $B$, then $\frac{1}{2N}$ is not in any element of $B$, thus $B$ does not cover $]0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Your open cover does cover all $]0,1[$.

Let $x \in ]0,1[$ then $0 < x < 1$.  Let $n$ be a positive integer so that $n > \frac 1x$.  (The integers are not bounded so there *will* be such an integer-- this is actually one of the consequences of the Archimedean Property; it's something that actually has to be proven but... that's for another post.)

So $n > \frac 1x$ so $0 < \frac 1n < x$.  So $x \in ]\frac 1n, 2[$.  So all points $x$ in $A$ are covered by your subcover.

And I assume you figured out that now finite subset of this cover successfully covers? (as per Jorge Fernandez Hidalgo's answer shows.)